# Beautiful Soup Unicode encode error

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup

I am trying the following code with a particular HTML file

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re
import codecs
import sys
f = open('test1.html')
html = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
body = soup.body.contents
para = soup.findAll('p')
print str(para).encode('utf-8')
```

I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How do I debug this?

I do not get any error when I remove the call to print function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`str(para)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str) builtin is trying to use the default (`ascii`) encoding for the unicode in `para`.
This is done **before** the `encode()` call:

```
>>> s=u'123\u2019'
>>> str(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> s.encode("utf-8")
'123\xe2\x80\x99'
>>>
```

Try encoding `para` directly, maybe by applying `encode("utf-8")` to each list element.