# ValueError: unsupported format character 'a' (0x61) at index 79

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape the data from a website using beautiful soup4 and python. Here is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
i = 0
for i in xrange(0,38):
    page=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.sfap.org/klsfaprep_search?page={}&type=1&strname=&loc=&op=Lancer%20la%20recherche&form_build_id=form-72a297de309517ed5a2c28af7ed15208&form_id=klsfaprep_search_form" %i) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    for eachuniversity in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'field-item odd'}):
        print ''.join(eachuniversity.findAll(text=True)).encode('utf-8')
    print ',\n'
i= i+ 1
```

I think the problem is in the URL that I have given and in the increment statement. I am able to scrape page by page. But only when I give the xrange.

Comment: You might need to [encode('utf-8') sooner](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2627117/1681480) before processing it... Also, your i values are not used (outside the loop) and are you sure you want page zero?

Comment: Yes. Paging start from 0 to 38. So how do I give it?

Comment: Just use @falsetru's answer -- the loop seems right (goes up to 37, not 38). I just thought that pages in URLs usually start at one not zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reason of the `ValueError`

You're mixing `{}` formatting with `%` formatting.

```
>>> '{}%20la' % 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: unsupported format character 'a' (0x61) at index 6
>>> '{}%20la'.format(1)
'1%20la'
```

I recommend you to use `{}` formatting, because in URL, there are multiple `%`s.

```
page=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.sfap.org/klsfaprep_search?page={}&type=1&strname=&loc=&op=Lancer%20la%20recherche&form_build_id=form-72a297de309517ed5a2c28af7ed15208&form_id=klsfaprep_search_form".format(i))
```

### Complete code

You don't need `i = 0` and `i = i + 1` because `for i in xrange(0,38)` take care of it.

```
import urllib2 # Import standard library module first. (PEP-8)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for i in xrange(0,38):
    page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.sfap.org/klsfaprep_search?page={}&type=1&strname=&loc=&op=Lancer%20la%20recherche&form_build_id=form-72a297de309517ed5a2c28af7ed15208&form_id=klsfaprep_search_form" .format(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    for eachuniversity in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'field-item odd'}):
        print ''.join(eachuniversity.findAll(text=True)).encode('utf-8')
    print ',\n'
```

Comment: How do I push the output into a .xlx file with comma separated?

Comment: @Venky, Use [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to do that.

Comment: It is becoming hard for me to write it into a csv file because the data are messed up and it is quiet not falling in the exact column as I want. Is there any way I can make it fall in the exact column?

Comment: @Venky, I thought `.xlx` is similar to `.csv` (becasue of `comma separated`). I don't know about `.xlx`. Sorry.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to write in csv only. In that itself it is messed up