# Beginner Python & Beautiful Soup Module : Unicode u2122

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup

I'm running the following code to get a prettify version of the open and close tags of an html file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("NATI_front_page.htm"))

print soup.originalEncoding

print (soup.prettify())
```

However I get this error.

```
File "front_page_pretty.py", line 8, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
nicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2122' in position 61769:   character maps to <undefined>
```

What I am trying to get is something like this:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm new to python, beautiful soup and unicode. I have looked on stack overflow for a question like this and I did not see any, so I posted this question. How would I resolve this issue? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: is it convenient to post a link to the HTML file? i think it's possible to make beautiful decode utf8 properly if you open the html file correctly. i've worked with beautfiulsoup with utf8 file before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is happening because you are trying to print the output. This will try to force ascii on the characters in the result from beautiful soup. This is almost the same as this question though:

[Beautiful Soup Unicode encode error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627071/beautiful-soup-unicode-encode-error/12443633#12443633)

Hope that helps. I'd recommend reading up on how python handles character encodings. A good place to start is here:

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in Windows and Windows console is using cp437 encoding you are getting the error
& if you only want to get rid of the error try adding this to your code:

```
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,'cp437','backslashreplace')
```

It will give you an output that is readable, though it will not print the character u'\u2122'

Possibly you can learn more from here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884036/unicodeencodeerror-in-python-on-windows-console/20885442)