# UnicodeEncodeError in Python on Windows Console

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I'm having the following error while recursing the files in a directory and printing file names in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python33\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position
53: character maps to <undefined>
```

According to the error, one of the characters in the file name string is `\u2013` which is an EN DASH `–` character different  from the commonly seen `-` minus character.

I have checked my Windows encoding which is set to `437`. Now, I see that I have two options to workaround this by either changing the encoding of Windows console or convert the characters in get from the file names to suit the console encoding. How would I go do that in Python 3.3?

Answer (score 5):

Windows console is using cp437 encoding and there is a character \u2013 that isn't supported by that encoding. Try adding this to your code:

```
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,'cp437','backslashreplace')
```

Comment: Is there a solution for Python 2?

Comment: @iamstudio, the issues is `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'buffer'` for `sys.stdout.buffer` on Python 2.

Comment: `python -c "import sys;sys.stdout.buffer"`

Comment: @techtonik Sorry! My bad. It may help you: https://gist.github.com/iamsudip/43e250d7b26f590c3d6c

Comment: @techtonik Read this too: http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/Encoding_of_Python_stdout

Comment: You can paste it as a Python2/3 compatible answer. =)

Comment: I still didn't have time to test the latest gist, but I guess it should work. Not sure if it will work in Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

> or convert the characters in get from the file names to suit the console encoding

Probably the console encoding is already correct (can't tell from the error message though). Code page 437 simply doesn't include that character so you won't be able to print it.

You can reopen `stdout` with a text encoder that has a fallback encoding, as demonstrated in iamsudip's answer which uses `backslashreplace`, to at least get readable (if not reliably recoverable) output instead of an error.

> changing the encoding of Windows console

You can do this by executing the console command `chcp 1252` before running Python, but that will still only give you a different limited repertoire of printable characters - including U+2013, but not many other Unicode characters.

In theory you can `chcp` to 65001 to get UTF-8 which would allow you to print any character. Unfortunately there are serious bugs in the C runtime's standard IO implementation, which usually make this unusable in practice.

This sorry state of affairs affects all applications that use the MS C runtime's stdio library calls, including Python and most other languages, with the result that Unicode on the Windows console just doesn't work in most cases.

If you really have to get Unicode out to the Windows console you can use the Win32 `WriteConsoleW` API directly using `ctypes`, but it's not much fun.

Comment: Python 3.3 should be good with code page 65001, see http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.3.html#codecs

Comment: @MarkRansom: It isn't in my experience. It seems the problem is for a console handle Windows internally routes `WriteFile` to `WriteConsoleA`, which returns the number of decoded Unicode characters instead of the number of bytes written. `WriteFile` happily returns this incorrect number back to the CRT's `write` function.

Comment: +1 @eryksun's description matches my experience of this bug. I found the same behaviour from the read operations too, which often results in a process stalled, waiting for further input that will never come. I'm not sure if it's the CRT or `WriteFile` to blame but whichever it is there is a workaround present to fix the behaviour for ANSI-default multibyte codepages like 932 and 936, but not for 65001. It is very sad that MS have still not fixed this known problem over many, many years.

Comment: [ANSICON](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) has a fix for the issue I described. It hooks `WriteConsoleA` to inject support for ANSI escape sequences. You can you can tell it to return the number of bytes instead of characters by setting the environment variable `ANSICON_API=[!]program;...`.

Comment: It replaces `WriteConsoleA` with [`MyWriteConsoleA`](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/blob/v1.66/ANSI.c#L1552), where it will *"[f]udge the (presumably) correct count"*. It also replaces `WriteFile` with [`MyWriteFile`](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/blob/v1.66/ANSI.c#L1620), which redirects to `MyWriteConsoleA` for a console handle.