# Cpickle invalid load key error with a weird key at the end

Tags: python, python-2.7, storage, pickle

I just tried to update a program i wrote and i needed to add another pickle file. So i created the blank .pkl and then use this command to open it(just as i did with all my others):

```
with open('tryagain.pkl', 'r') as input:
  self.open_multi_clock = pickle.load(input)
```

only this time around i keep getting this really weird error for no obvious reason,

`cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'Γ'.`

The pickle file does contain the necessary information to be loaded, it is an exact match to other blank .pkl's that i have and they load fine. I don't know what that last key is in the error but i suspect that could give me some incite if i know what it means.

Comment: how did you pickle to the file?

Comment: I have the header of a blank .pkl file and i just copy it into my new blank .pkl

Comment: why do you have blank pickle files?

Comment: It was just added to my program so , there just hasn't been any info written to it. I don't mean completely blank, as i said it does have the necessary header in it to make it a .pkl. So its not completely empty their is just no data currently stored in it because it hasn't actually opened yet.

Comment: I still don't get it, why are you manually copying data, why not dump it using pickle?

Comment: Yes, i see what you mean i just thought originally it would be better to just copy into a new file but i have just dumped it instead, none the less it still throws the same error.

Comment: if it does not throw an error in the other pickle files, how could it do it in this file, what have you done differently?

Comment: I have figured out the solution, and I'm gonna write up my own answer. Your questions led to the answer though, thank you.

Comment: If you think my answer not proper let me know, and ill just delete it. Although i think it could be helpful with people new to using pickle files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So have have figured out the solution to this problem, and i thought I'd take the time to list some examples of what to do and what not to do when using pickle files. Firstly, the solution to this was to simply just make a plain old .txt file and dump the pickle data to it.
If you are under the impression that you have to actually make a new file and save it with a .pkl ending you would be wrong. I was creating my .pkl's with notepad++ and saving them as .pkl's. Now from my experience this does work sometimes and sometimes it doesn't, if your semi-new to programming this may cause a fair amount of confusion as it did for me. All that being said, i recommend just using plain old .txt files. It's the information stored inside the file not necessarily the extension that is important here.

```
#Notice file hasn't been pickled.
#What not to do. No need to name the file .pkl yourself.
with open('tryagain.pkl', 'r') as input:
  self.open_multi_clock = pickle.load(input)
```

The proper way:

```
#Pickle your new file
with open(filename, 'wb') as output:
  pickle.dump(obj, output, -1)

#Now open with the original .txt ext. DONT RENAME.
with open('tryagain.txt', 'r') as input:
  self.open_multi_clock = pickle.load(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

Gonna guess the pickled data is throwing off portability by the outputted characters. I'd suggest base64 encoding the pickled data before writing it to file. What what I ran:

```
import base64
import pickle
value_p = pickle.dumps("abdfg")
value_p_b64 = base64.b64encode(value_p)
f = file("output.pkl", "w+")
f.write(value_p_b64)
f.close()
for line in open("output.pkl", 'r'):
    readable += pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(line))
>>> readable
'abdfg'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna give this a go in my code and ill accept it if it works. Although, do you have any clue why this is happening all of a sudden when their is no apparent difference between this pickle file and the ones that work fine? Seems like a lot of extra code for a simple task ya know lol?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, I'm fairly sure the answer to this lies in that symbol at the end.

Comment: Could be. But manually copying and pasting is gonna mess with the encoding. i.e. magic of python making things print pretty. An example of how input/output (concretely the local keyboard for your screen, so you can read in your language) not working out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884036/unicodeencodeerror-in-python-on-windows-console

Comment: Will you delete your previous ".pkl" file and give my code a go please? It worked on my machine.